# What's going on with my CSS print?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Here is my CSS code:

```
 @media print
        {
            body *
            {
                visibility:hidden;
            }
            #printable *
            {
                visibility:visible;
            }
            #printable
            {
                margin:0px;
                color : #000000;
                background : #ffffff;
                filter: Gray();
                filter: url('#grayscale'); 
                -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
                filter: grayscale(100%);
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
            }

            @page
            {
                size:auto;
                margin:0mm;
            }

        }
```

I have div like this

```
<div class="row" id="printable">

   ...

</div>
```

When i print in the web the upper part has too much blank and the main content start almost a half in the paper. Is there something wrong with my css?

Sorry if i cant show an image..

Comment: cause u have used `visibility:hidden`. It just makes the elements invisible, but they take up their original space. Thats why blank spaces are there

Comment: so what should i do. if i use `display:none` no display at all

Comment: you can use `display:none` for `body *` but then for `#printable` provide `display:block` and for `#printable *` you can provide `display` property value as requred, inline or block etc. you will need to be specific about that

Comment: I already do that and still nothings happen.. if i use `display:none` and use `display:block` or `display:inline` in `#printable` still not working. Thanks buddy i will still keep on trying with it.

Comment: `#printable` should not be under any container that is hidden, and elements inside the `#printable` should not be hidden. This will solve the issue. Try applying this styles on your webpage itself. I just did it here on stackoverflow site and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Error! #printable is still having visibility:hidden, change the code to:

```
 @media print
        {
            body *
            {
                visibility:hidden;
            }
            #printable *
            {
                visibility:visible;
            }
            #printable
            {
                margin:0px;
                color : #000000;
                background : #ffffff;
                filter: Gray();
                filter: url('#grayscale'); 
                -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
                filter: grayscale(100%);
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
    visibility:visible;
            }

            @page
            {
                size:auto;
                margin:0mm;
            }

        }
```